# I can't open the image. Parsing doesn't work

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I can't open "url" in "images". 
Parsing doesn't work. Please help. Thank you.

```
"images": [
        {
          "url": "https://ktar.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ap_27df5153e3bf48198ebcfd40900446d6.jpg",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 853,
          "title": "Arizona reports 124 new coronavirus cases, five additional deaths",
          "attribution": null
```

## =======================================================

=======================================================
API

```
{
      "path": "_news/2020-04-01-arizona-reports-124-new-coronavirus-cases-five-additional-deaths.md",
      "title": "Arizona reports 124 new coronavirus cases, five additional deaths",
      "excerpt": "The Arizona health department reported 124 new cases of coronavirus and five additional deaths on Wednesday morning, a day after the state's \"stay at home\" order went into effect.",
      "heat": 145,
      "tags": [
        "US"
      ],
      "type": "article",
      "webUrl": "https://ktar.com/story/3056413/arizona-reports-124-new-coronavirus-cases-five-additional-deaths/",
      "ampWebUrl": "https://ktar.com/story/3056413/arizona-reports-124-new-coronavirus-cases-five-additional-deaths/amp/",
      "cdnAmpWebUrl": "https://ktar-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/ktar.com/story/3056413/arizona-reports-124-new-coronavirus-cases-five-additional-deaths/amp/",
      "publishedDateTime": "2020-04-01T09:09:00-07:00",
      "updatedDateTime": null,
      "provider": {
        "name": "KTAR News",
        "domain": "ktar.com",
        "images": null,
        "publishers": null,
        "authors": null
      },
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "https://ktar.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ap_27df5153e3bf48198ebcfd40900446d6.jpg",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 853,
          "title": "Arizona reports 124 new coronavirus cases, five additional deaths",
          "attribution": null
        }
      ],
      "locale": "en-us",
      "categories": [
        "news"
      ],
      "topics": [
        "Coronavirus in US",
        "Coronavirus",
        "New Cases"
      ]
    }
```

## ======================================================

======================================================

```
//  SPORTNEWSVC.swift
//  Hero

import Alamofire
import Kingfisher
import UIKit


class NewsVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var news = [Article]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getArticles()

    }

    func getArticles() {

        let parameters: Parameters = ["Subscription-Key": "3009d4ccc29e4808af1ccc25c69b4d5d"]

        Alamofire.request("https://api.smartable.ai/coronavirus/news/US", parameters: parameters).responseData { (response) in

            guard let data = response.data else { return }

            do {

//                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
//                print(json)

                let topHeadlinesResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(TopHeadlinesResponse.self, from: data)
                self.news = topHeadlinesResponse.news
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }

    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return news.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ArticleCell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleCell else { return UICollectionViewCell ()}

        let article = news[indexPath.item]
        cell.populate(with: article)

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let height: CGFloat = 277

        let width = (collectionView.frame.width / 2) - 2

        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        return size

    }

}
```

## ======================================================

======================================================

```
//  Article.swift
//  Hero
//

import Foundation

struct Article: Decodable {
    let headline: String
    let url: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case headline = "title"
        case url
    }

}
```

## ======================================================

======================================================

```
//
//  ArticleCell.swift
//  Hero

import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class ArticleCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var articleImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headlieLabel: UILabel!

    func populate(with article: Article){
        headlieLabel.text = article.headline

        if let url = article.url {
            let url = URL(string: url)
            articleImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        }

    }

}
```

## ======================================================

======================================================

```
import Foundation


struct TopHeadlinesResponse: Decodable {
    let news: [Article]
}
```

Comment: There is no key `news` on the top level of the JSON

Comment: "Parsing doesn't work"? How do you know that exactly? `print(error)` is this called?

Answer (score 0):

```
*struct TopHeadLinesResponse: Codable {
    let path, title, excerpt: String
    let heat: Int
    let tags: [String]
    let type: String
    let webURL, ampWebURL, cdnAmpWebURL: String
    let publishedDateTime: Date
    let updatedDateTime: JSONNull?
    let provider: Provider
    let images: [Image]
    let locale: String
    let categories, topics: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case path, title, excerpt, heat, tags, type
        case webURL
        case ampWebURL
        case cdnAmpWebURL
        case publishedDateTime, updatedDateTime, provider, images, locale, categories, topics
    }
}

// MARK: - Image
struct Image: Codable {
    let url: String
    let width, height: Int
    let title: String
    let attribution: JSONNull?
}

// MARK: - Provider
struct Provider: Codable {
    let name, domain: String
    let images, publishers, authors: JSONNull?
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
 extension UIImageView {
func loadImagee(_ urlString: String?, onSuccess: ((UIImage) -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.image = UIImage()
    guard let string = urlString else { return }
    guard let url = URL(string: string) else { return }
    self.sd_setImage(with: url) { (image, error, type, url) in
        if onSuccess != nil, error == nil {
            onSuccess!(image!)
        }
    }
}
}

// try using SD Web library code is above install SDweb instead of // king fisher
// check your struct also check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310054/im-having-troubles-displaying-an-image-from-json-in-a-table-view*
```

Comment: @DayMan try using SDweb library I typed the code in extension.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that "images" in the JSON response you get is an array and you need to reflect this fact in Codable structure. The Decoding magic needs you to follow JSON data structure and namings: so if you meet field 'width' inside 'image' dictionary - you need to have a field named 'width' inside an 'image' field (e.g. having image as a separate struct)

you can read more about Decodables [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

```
struct NewsApiResponse : Decodable {
    let status : String
    let updatedDateTime : Date?
    let news : [Article]
}

struct Article : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let title : String
    let excerpt : String
    let webUrl : String
    let publishedDateTime : Date?
    let images : [Image]
}

struct Image : Decodable {
    let url : String
    let width : Int
    let height : Int
    let title : String
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still figuring it out